# copying two lists of ObservableCollection types in c#(wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have the following class in Wpf

```
 public class test
 {
     public int id;
     public string name;
 }
```

As well as two of the list of ObservableCollection types that I've made right

```
    private ObservableCollection<Test> ClassTest;
    private ObservableCollection<Test> TempClassTest;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClassTest = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        TempClassTest = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        ClassTest.Add(new Test() { id = 1, name = "T1" });
        ClassTest.Add(new Test() { id = 2, name = "T2" });
        ClassTest.Add(new Test() { id = 3, name = "T3" });
    }
```

The problem is that whenever the test method is changed, it changes in the first variable like the following code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TempClassTest = ClassTest;
        TempClassTest[0].id = 1110;
    }
```

Now the value of ClassTest[0] is id=1110

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes, this is the way it works. When you put `TempClassTest = ClassTest` you are saying "make `TempClassTest` point to the same instance of the `ObservableCollection<Test>` that `ClassTest` points to". It is **not making a copy of the `ObservableCollection<Test>`** and it's **not making a copy of each element in the list**.

Comment: This is way the observable collection works. Read its [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And you are assigning reference of `ClassTest` to `TempClassTest`, So both are pointing to same memory location. That's why it is updating value in `ClassTest` as well.

Comment: Instead you can do that `TempClassTest = new ObservableCollection<Test>(ClassTest)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# - Read about reference types. 
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection is a reference type. Following line of code:

```
TempClassTest = ClassTest;
```

Creates a shallow copy (it does not create entirly new member wise list).

The item in the Collection is also a ReferenceType, so you need to Deep Clone the item again.

Do something like:

```
public class Test: ICloneable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return new Sample { Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name };
        }
    }
```

And then,

```
ObservableCollection<Test> coll1 = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            coll1.Add(new Test{ Id = 1 });
            coll1.Add(new Test{ Id = 2 });
            coll1.Add(new Test{ Id = 3 });

ObservableCollection<Test> coll2 = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            foreach (var item in coll1)
            {
                coll2.Add(item.Clone() as Test);
            }

            coll2[0].Id = 1500;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but with this code again makes changes

Comment: TempClassTest = new ObservableCollection<Test>(ClassTest.ToList());
            TempClassTest[0].id = 1110;

Comment: Reason is that the Item in your collection is a reference type again. You need to make a Clone of it too.

Answer (score 0):

the first variable object is assigned to second variable. so, the first variable and second variable pointing the same memory address. so, you change any value of first or second it should effect on two  variables.

You use clone

[Copy Observable Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018277/copy-observablecollection-to-another-observablecollection)